# Send array of Objects to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to send an array of json objects to server:

```
var objectData = [
    {  Description: "Bezeichnung", Value: "1", Name: "Betrag (Brutto)" },
    { Description: "Dies ist die erste Bezeicnung", Value: "101", Name: "11,90" },
    { Description: "Dies ist die zweite Bezeicnung", Value: "12", Name: "11,90" }
];

$.ajax({
    url: "/system/createinvoice",
    data: JSON.stringify({ pos: objectData }) ,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
});
```

C#

```
public class InvoicePos
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

[POST("/system/createinvoice")]
public void newquestion2(InvoicePos[] pos)
{
   // pos is always null       
}
```

Comment: you know that json is of type string not array?

Comment: what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I see in your code that you expect `pos` to be an array. I am not too familiar with C#, but if it does not make any kind of conversion for you of the the json string (which you got over http), so it is still a string and you will need to convert it to an array yourself.

Comment: asp.net mvc does the conversion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dataType` property is saying what you expect *back* from the server.  Try setting the `contentType`:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data: JSON.stringify({ pos: @objectData })
```

Also, check what is being rendered in the View through the browser. The reason you are getting null is likely because JavaScript is not getting a proper value.

Answer (score 0):

function SendArrayOfObjects()
        {
            var things = [{ id: 1, color: 'red' }, { id: 2, color: 'blue' }, { id: 3, color: 'yellow' }];

```
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/MyServices.aspx/GetData")%>",
              data: JSON.stringify({ objdata: things }),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function()
            {
                $("#msg").html("data sent successfully!");
            },
            error: function()
            {

                $("#msg").html(" Can not send data!");
            }
        });


    }
```