# pass jquery array of objects to mvc action which accepts a list object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in my view which has only one textarea input initially and user can add more textarea inputs if he wants with jquery. My problem is related to second case. After submitting the form i am getting an array of objects in console but when i am passing this array to mvc action in my controller it is coming to be null.
I have tried these solution but did not succeed:

[Send array of Objects to MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920711/send-array-of-objects-to-mvc-controller)

[POST a list of objects to MVC 5 Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311679/post-a-list-of-objects-to-mvc-5-controller)

here is my code:-

jquery code:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#addTextForm', function () {
   console.log($(this));
   var frmData = $(this).serializeArray();
   console.log(frmData);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: '/Dashboard/UploadText',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       data: JSON.stringify({ obj: frmData }),
       success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
       },
       error: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
       }
   });
  return false;
});
```

MVC action:

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadText(SliderTextList obj)
{
  return "success";      
}
```

my object class:

```
public class SliderText
{
  [JsonProperty("Id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("SlideName")]
  public string SlideName { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("Content")]
  public string Content { get; set; }

}
public class SliderTextList
{
  public List<SliderText> AllTexts { get; set; }
}
```

I have to store the `Content` in json file with `Id` and `SlideName`, so i think  i have to pass a list object in mvc action `Uploadtext` which is coming out to be null always. Please help.

Comment: check in console post tab what data it is sending in

Comment: If you have generated the view correctly (i.e. the names or your dynamically created objects have the correct indexers), then all you need is `data: $('#addTextForm').serialize()` and remove `contentType: 'application/json',`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it still didn't worked

Comment: Then you have not generated the form controls correctly. Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options for dynamically adding collection items. You have not shown your code so impossible to know what your doing wrong.

Comment: The elements you creating should have `name="AllTexts[0].SlideName"`, `name="AllTexts[1].SlideName"` etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke which code you want? Also in my form, i have more than one textareas with value of name attribute is `Content`. The other two properties I want to generate them in my action method

Comment: You cannot have multiple textareas with `name="Content"` - the `name` attributes must relate to the model your posting to so they need to be `name="AllTexts[0].Content"`, `name="AllTexts[1].Content"` etc. Read the links I gave you.

Comment: But if all your editing is the `Content` property, then they could be all `name="Content"` but only if you change the method signature to `[HttpPost]public ActionResultUploadText(IEnumerable<string> content)` and then you build your collection of `SliderText` objects based on the the values in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('submit', '#addTextForm', function () {
   var listData=[];
   var oInputs = new Array();
   oInputs = document.getElementsByTag('input' );
   var k=1;
   for ( i = 0; i < oInputs.length; i++ )
   {  
       if ( oInputs[i].type == 'textarea' )
       {
          var obj=new Object();
          obj.Id=k;
          obj.SlideName=oInputs[i].Name;
          obj.Content=oInputs[i].Value;
          K=parseInt(k)+1;
          listData.push(obj);
       }
   }
   $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: '/Dashboard/UploadText',
           contentType: 'application/json',
           data: JSON.stringify(listData),
           success: function (data) {
                       console.log(data);
           },
           error: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
          }
     });
    return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sever side expects a string as argument `obj` as a query string I think this is what you need.

```
data: { 
    obj: JSON.stringify(frmData) 
},
```

as an alternative using as Stephen suggested on the comments

```
data: { 
    obj: $('#addTextForm').serialize()
},
```

Comment: No, that was not my suggestion - its just `data: $('#addTextForm').serialize(),` which will work if OP has generated the form controls correctly - ie. `name=[0].SlideName"`, `name=[1].SlideName` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not much familiar with ASP, but by the looks of it `SliderTextList obj` which is expecting a `json` string as the parameter. If we post `data: $('#addTextForm').serialize()` then the ajax page will be receiviving this arguments as `'id': idvalue, 'SlideName': SlideNameValue, 'Content': ContentValue`, right? That thought made me make that adjustment.

Comment: No that's not correct. If the `contentType: 'application/json'` is removed, then the data will be posted as the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which is the default expected by the `DefaultModelBinder` (and it will be bound correctly)